# How to avoid counting numbers when do calculation in a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I am working on a python algorithm. I have built a for loop to generate the numbers i want. I am going to use these numbers as indices to generate a string called `constraint_sty3`.

Here is a part of my code:

```
def constraint():
    val=4
    ind=[]
    for i in range(1,7):
        for j in range(val,val+i):
            val = val+1
            ind.append(j)
            if(i < 6):
                boundNode.insert(j, 'x%d' % (j-(2*i+1)))
            constraint_sty3 = str(boundNode[(j+1])]
```

**My problem is when calculating `j+1` , it appears it is not doing the right calculation but doing the counting at the same time.** Like a `j=j+1`. All the other j ,i -related `str(boundNode[])`like `str(boundNode[j])` work well but only this contains `j+1` return a problematic result.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on the last line of your code:

```
constraint_sty3 = str(boundNode[(j+1])]
```

it should be:

```
constraint_sty3 = str(boundNode[(j+1)])
```

But i dont think this is the error

But by putting (j+1) inside brackets [ ] it will count plus one on that array/list
You should do the calculation before and then append it.

Comment: But I have already generate `boundNode[]` list. I want to use `j+1` as an index. Is there any solution to this?